# Not closed files in julia writes different output?

Tags: julia

I have a julia program that simulate an ensemble of systems.
Basically in each realization I record observables as a function of time and write,
per realization, the results to a file.

I noticed just recently that I had a file where I write my results that has not the proper

```
close(filename)
```

command. Just to be sure, would there be any error in my numerics if I have not properly close the files that I use to write?

Since julia doesn't raise an error when it compiles, I would like to know if this is done implicitly by Julia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file will be automatically closed at the end of the script (or, if its opened in a function, at the end of the function).

More precisely, it will be closed when the file pointer goes out of scope.

Even more precisely, it will be closed when the file pointer gets garbage collected.

Comment: So if I have several files, one per realization, then all files will be close at the end of the module, right?

Comment: Yep, everything gets closed

Comment: I haven't checked, but I'm pretty sure that the file will only get closed when the File is garbage collected, which could be much later than when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

All `IOStream`s will be closed and their buffers flushed before the Julia process exits.  However, the time at which the `IOStream` will be closed is unpredictable.

The exact mechanism is as follows.  The `open` function, which creates a file `IOStream`, registers a *finaliser* with the garbage collector.  Periodically, Julia invokes the garbage collector, which destroys any unreachable data structures; if it destroys an `IOStream`, it runs the associated finaliser which closes the file.

Since the time at which the garbage collector is run is unpredictable, it is better to explicitly close the `IOStream` yourself: you should consider the finalisation mechanism as a mere additional security measure in case you forget to call `close`.